# Baking a texture to another object comes out distorted/displaced

Tags: texture-baking

I've been trying to bake generated gradients from simpler objects to objects with more irregular topology, but it comes out slightly displaced. Is that normal?

These are the objects, selected in the order of baking:
[image]

With these UVs:
[image]

And modifiers (Ring is the smaller object I'm baking from):
[image]

Materials (first is source, second is target):
[image]

[image]

And finally bake settings:
[image]

And this is how it comes out (grey is unbaked, the other frame is baked with the ring object hidden):
[image]

I also tried changing the Extrusion and Max Ray Distance values in the bake, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Also tried a different offset for the shrinkwrap, and interestingly enough, if I make the ring appear inside the object, it will bake correctly, but the incorrect texture gets baked under it at the same time.
[image]
(ring object is hidden here)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to make the ring appear inside the cylinder and change *Max Ray Distance* to something other than `0` (`0.01` in this case) at the same time.